# Memcache clear based on the key

Tags: memcached

We are using the memcached server for caching the data, when ever we do any changes on configuration files we need to restart memcached server , which leads to the over load on the server.

Is it possible to clear the memcached based on the key value pair or by passing any specific input so that part of the memcached will be cleared.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can do it with one php script with inbuilt function

```
<?php

/* procedural API */
$memcache_obj = memcache_connect('memcache_host', 11211);

/* item will be deleted by the server */
memcache_delete($memcache_obj, 'key_to_delete');

/* OO API */
$memcache_obj = new Memcache;
$memcache_obj->connect('memcache_host', 11211);

$memcache_obj->delete('key_to_delete');

?>
```

look for detail http://php.net/manual/en/memcache.delete.php